# javascript substring extract

Tags: php, javascript, string

I have a javascript script where there are lines, a example is :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOeLP1WdjFc&feature=related
```

I want to extract the substring that is after "watch?=" and before "&feature",
its pattern is:

1) it is  after "watch?="

2) it is before "&feature",

3) it is a 11-character string

I know other scripts could be easy, but now I only need javascript, 
if it is really impossible, then php is acceptable, 
how to achieve this?
thanks!

Comment: Nothing is impossible with JavaScript's string interface.

Comment: This regex should work `\Wv=([^&$]+)` to extract the value of the video ID

Comment: Use a URL parser to get the *value of the `v` parameter* instead of such a clunky, error-prone pattern

Answer (score 3):

Try this ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KZq8v/)):

```
var s = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOeLP1WdjFc&feature=related";

var left = "watch?v=";
var right = "&feature";

var parsed = s.substring(s.indexOf(left) + left.length, s.indexOf(right));

console.log(parsed);​
```

This is  a very rough, quick answer so I'd recommend looking into regular expressions for a more scalable method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to formulate your requirements:

```
var res = url.match(/watch?=(.{11})&feature/);
if (res != null)
    return res[1];
```

Not that this would work (extract the content of the `v` parameter), but it does what you described.

Comment: I only get null with your script

Comment: Sure, me too for the example url you pasted. A "valid" url where your extraction mechanism matches would be `http://www.youtube.com/watch?=FOeLP1WdjFc&feature…`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need using JavaScript [`.indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [`.substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) methods.

```
var index = url.indexOf('?v=') + 3;
alert(url.substring(index, index + 11));
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wRYEc/).

Comment: Yes, you might use those methods; yet your code does not what the OP described

Comment: How do you know? My guess is that he wants value of `v` (hint: 11 characters) ;)

Comment: Sure, that's what I guess, too :-) Yet he said explicitly he wanted a 11-character substring between `watch?=` and `&feature`…

Comment: so exactly what  is Bergi's opinion on this script snippet?

Comment: @user1769686: better use `url.match(/[?&]v=[^&#]*/)[0].substr(3)`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can use standard function [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse a URL and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse query string to extract an individual GET parameter like `v`.